# Python requests and instagram

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I am playing around with the instagram api and requests, trying to get past the OAuth. I use `r = requests.get(...)` and follow the instagram doc. However, the output from requests is never what I expect. I am having 2 issues that are somewhat similar.

1) If I send the wrong parameters I expect to get back JSON looking like

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}
```

Which is what I see if I paste the string from `r.url` into the browser. However `r.json()` simply fails and gives me

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

2) A correct response should redirect me to my redirect url, which will also include a code. Again, this works correctly when pasting `r.url` into a browser. I am successfully redirected as expected. Requests does not appear to redirect me, even with explicitly set `allow_redirects=False`. I only need to read the code from the url. How can I get requests to give me the final url for me to extract the code?

Edit: Might as well include some code.

```
def get_code(client_id, redirect_uri, scope="basic"):
    params = {"client_id": client_id,
              "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
              "response_type": "code",
              "scope": scope}
    r = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/',
                     params=params)
    # print r.url
    # print r.json()
    return r
```

Comment: How are you validating? Also a link to the docs would be good

Comment: I was tried both the implicit and explicit methods (they are essentially the same for this step). Here are the docs: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: The json does not get parsed because it is html to a login form. Try clearing your cookies for instagram.com in your browser and you should see the login form.

Comment: Also, take a look at [python-instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram).

Comment: Did you read the docs? *At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where to grant your app access to her Instagram data.*

Comment: @simonKirsten that is outdated, no longer supported, and straight up does not work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see that, but then why does following the url in a browser redirect me accordingly while requests does not.

Comment: @Shatners, requests does not know about any cookies in your browser. You would not expect to have to validate the app every time in your browser, as for requests each time you use it it knows nothing about previous runs. What is your end goal? I think I see a simple way to do it with requests, give me a couple of minutes

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Not sure how I overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you in the [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) exactly what happen, *At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where to grant your app access to her Instagram data*, if you run the snippet below you will see a login box in your browser:

```
import requests
import  webbrowser
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
params = {"client_id": client_id,
          "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
          "response_type": "code",
          "scope": scope}
with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=0) as f:
    r = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/',
                     params=params)
    f.write(r.content)
    webbrowser.open(f.name)
```